# Bootstrap BuildTools - Bundle Install - Could not locate Gemfile

Tags: bootstrap-4, build-tools

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/build-tools/

I'm following these instructions to install buildtools on my mac and I'm getting this error.

```
Could not locate Gemfile
```

when I run which bundle I get this,

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/bundle
```

The version of ruby is,

```
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
```

why can't I finish the bundle install and why is it showing MAMP as my which bundle? What am I doing wrong here, any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

On https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/build-tools/
where it says "install Bundler with `gem install bundler`, and finally run `bundle install`", it should probably say to run `bundle init` before `bundle install`
The init command (for me, anyway) created the missing Gemfile.